# Program running as admin can't access some paths

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm creating a C# program which check signatures for all .exe files and do some other checks. The application request to run as admin with UAC, and checks it at start (We are sure is running with admin privileges).

However, when I check recursively some paths, I got folders where I don't have access. For example:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

is throwing:

```
 System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Application Data' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.AddSearchableDirsToStack(SearchData localSearchData)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at "the lines above"
```

Is there any way to access those paths? In case it's not possible, a way to GetFiles skips those paths without stopping is also very appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give me one folder example? I would like to see this folder permissions.

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Application Data` as in the exception message

Comment: It's in the exception, 'C:\ProgramData\Application Data' for example. The PC is a standard Win 7

Comment: Search this site for `[c#] System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. This question has been asked (and answered) here many times before.

Comment: I mean return the Windows access control list (ACL) for a directory using Directory.GetAccessControl Method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you are an admin does not mean you can access everything!
E.g. a users personal folder is also not accessible for an admin "by default", but as an admin you can "give yourself that right".

So either you change the rights on all such folders or just leave out such folders.

*UPDATE:*

> In case it's not possible, a way to GetFiles skips those paths without stopping is also very appreciated.

You could choose a recursive scan "per folder" (should be done anyhow IMO):

```
public void Scan(DirectoryInfo dir = null)
{
    if (dir == null)
    {
        dir = new DirectoryInfo(System.Environment
              .GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));
    }

    try
    {
        var dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        foreach (var subDir in dirs)
            Scan(subDir);

        var files = dir.GetFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var file in files)
            // check file
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // log error
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a personal folder... Any way to do it programmatically and revert it later?

Comment: "personal folder" was just an example - the important fact is it is very well possible to be not able to access folders even if you are an admin. Just open the properties dialog for such a folder and check the rights of the `Administrator` group in the security tab...

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a solution, as I need to run it for several paths in several PCs and should be done programmatically. Any way to GetFiles to skip those paths?

Comment: Another option is to turn on backup privilege.  That basically tells Windows to stop checking security permissions.  In some cases you have to also pass a special flag to the API function, but not for directory enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding read/write permissions on the files you are attempting to access via command prompt?

If you are only requiring access to this file temporary, it is best to remove the permissions after you are done with the reading/writing, otherwise, I would look into giving certain users permissions instead of modifying permissions in your file system. Either way works, depending on your goal.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419